# emailing contents of text fields advice needed xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, textbox, storyboard

when trying to email contents from text fields im having exceptions thrown.  I think im wiring them up wrong.

Im creating outlets for my text fields in .h, setting up my email button as an action.

In .m im implementing usual code for sending email. Ui message frame kit has been imported.

Now I need some help as thats not working for me.

To summarise:  How do i email whats in my text boxes?

Im using xcode 4.3 with storyboards

Thanks

Comment: If you show the actual error messages, it might give a clue.

Comment: ***Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextField isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89925e0'

Comment: Do a NSLog on the string you're comparing it to (or put a breakpoint in your code on this line of code and then examine the value of the variables). The "string" is probaby nil. Or not a string. Or already deallocated. Show us code and we might be able to help.

Comment: You can't compare a UITextField to a NSString.  It doesn't have an isEqualToString: method.  Try something like: `[yourField.text isEqualToStrin:...]`.

Comment: Ok perhaps i need to learn how to use strings with textboxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no tricks to emailing the contents of text boxes. You need help with some exception, you need to provide us the precise error and show us the relevant code. If you want to try to solve it on your own, you should debug the code, single stepping through the method that attempts to email the contents of your text boxes (see [Xcode 4 User Guide: Debugging and Analyzing Your Code](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW1); see the section about adding breakpoints and then the section about controlling execution).

Exceptions are generally the result of memory management problems (e.g. your code is trying to use some object that has already been released) so you might want to [enable zombies](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeDiagnostics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010402-CH9-SW1) if you haven't already. I also think that people do not sufficiently appreciate the value of Xcode's Analyze command on the Product menu (described in the aforementioned [Analyzing Your Code section](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/Debugging/Debugging.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW15)). This Analyze command will identify not only dangling pointers, but also some memory leaks. It's not perfect, but it's a good start.

People really shouldn't be posting questions here if they haven't first resolved the problems raised by Analyze (unless, of course, you need help fixing issues that Analyze raises). Personally, when I went through this Analyze exercise on my first big project, it was painful to clean up all the issues that it identified, but, more importantly, I suddenly "got it". I've been an IT professional for decades, have programmed in dozens (literally) of programming languages, but only after going through this painful exercise did I finally get the subtleties of Objective C memory management. Suddenly, rereading Apple's [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html), it all made perfect sense.

So, if you're still stymied, and the Analyze command did not identify any issues, and you ran the code through the debugger you were not able to identify why the exception was generated, then just provide us a detailed error message and show us the relevant code and I'm sure we'd be happy to help.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed reply and to everyone else, i dont understand how to interpret the errors and have no clue what zombies are, ive tried to find a tutorial for how to email content from my text fields but have not found anything relevant.  In fact getting any data inputed in any app seems to baffle me. Not only am I new xcode im new to programming.  Im a bit embarrassed to put my code here in case its really something stupid and I get loads of negative comments.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about being embarrassed about your code. We've all been there. You might get suggestions about what you might be able to do better, but that's what you're looking for, right? In terms of code samples that email content from text fields, you probably won't find that. You'll see examples of sending emails, which will consist of demonstrations of using MFMailComposeViewController and providing NSString values. You just need to know how to get data strings from your text fields (which is as easy as accessing the `text` property of your UITextField).

Comment: In answer to your zombie question, a common programming problem is that you might have a variable that points to an Objective C object that has been deallocated for one reason or another, but your code is still trying to use the pointer to that dead object. To help diagnose these problems, you can turn on zombies, in which the debugger will keep track of deallocated objects (get it, keep dead things alive; lol), so if you accidentally reference one of them, it can catch it and tell you about your mistake. In the absence of zombies, you might not know if you make this mistake.

Comment: Finally, I'd suggest if you're struggling with these sorts of things (UITextFields, memory management, etc.) that you check out some training resources. Here is a [StackOverflow discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403049/best-book-resources-for-learning-ios-programming) that references some good books and videos.

Comment: Thanks for the advice i really appreciate that, and will check out some more resources.  I can use the in app email function, i can build apps, where Im stuck is gathering the information from the boxes into the email function, once i figure it out the final piece of the puzzle it will make things a whole easier!  Thanks again

Comment: In interface builder, link your text boxes to UITextFields in your class (if you haven't already). In your "create email" program, you'll have a NSString for the body of the message, which you can initialize with something like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", myFirstTextField.text, mySecondTextField.text]` (or whatever) and then pass this NSString to your email method. Or if one of your text fields is the body of the email, then it's even easier; you just pass myEmailBodyTextField.text for the parameter of the email.

Comment: Wow, Ive finally got the contents of my text box to email, I have been overcomplicating this all this time, cant believe how easy that was when it clicked! Thank you so much for you help.  Its very very much appreciated!